# Скорость наше всё?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Доброго вечера все. Профессионалы и любители JavaScript. 
Я говорил ранее, что изучаю JS по учебнику "Выразительный JS"
Сейчас я нахожусь на главе DOM и иже с ним
Там приведён пример как легко с помощью рекурсии сделать поиск в body определённой фразы:

```
function searchStr(node, string){

    if(node.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) 
            if (searchStr(node.childNodes[i], string)) 
               return true;
        return false;
    }
    else if(node.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE) return 
    node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1

}
```

Вопрос вот в чём, я не понимаю зачем использовать рекурсию там, где можно использовать обычный код. Вот код, который делает тоже самое, только быстрее.

```
function searchStr(node, string){
    for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;i++)
        if(node.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) 
            return node.parentElement.innerText.indexOf(string) > -1;
}
```

На сам код пофигу, можно сделать немного изящнее, брать родителя сразу, но суть не в этом. Разве так важно пихать рекурсии везде где можно?

Делал сравнение по мс, первый код работает примерно в 5 раз медленнее второго.

Comment: Жесть. Зачем здесь, в таком случае, цикл? С тем же успехом функция могла состоять из одной последней строчки.

Comment: дак и у меня на любом уровне вложенности ищет. Только что проверил.

Comment: Почитайте, чем отличается `innerText` от `nodeValue`.

Comment: @Igor, выбрал это свойство за то, что он весь текст документа хранит в одной строке

Comment: @ДенисИванов - оставьте в Вашей функции только строчку с `return` - будет работать еще быстрее :)

Comment: @Igor, я это сделал ещё после первого комментария =)))

Comment: @ДенисИванов, _document.getElementsByClassName("u").firstChild_ - не на любом, если внутри элемента не будет текстовых нод, то ты ничего не найдешь

Answer (score 1):

> Разве так важно пихать рекурсии везде где можно?

Это был риторический вопрос? Нет, не так важно.

Ваше решение не эквивалентно рекурсивному. У Вас возможны *false positives*, когда искомая строка получается склеиванием двух кусков текста, находящихся в разных элементах.

```js
function searchStrTextbook(node, stringToFind) {
  if (node.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) 
      if (searchStrTextbook(node.childNodes[i], stringToFind)) 
        return true;
    return false;
  } else if(node.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE) {
    return node.nodeValue.indexOf(stringToFind) > -1;
  }
}

function searchStrDenis(node, stringToFind) {
  return node.parentElement.innerText.indexOf(stringToFind) > -1;
}

//console.log(document.body.innerText);
console.log(searchStrTextbook(document.body, "a" + "b"));
console.log(searchStrDenis(document.body, "a" + "b"));
```

```css
span{margin:10px;}
```

```html
Встречается ли в этом документе строка "a" + "b"?

<div><span>aaaa</span><span>bbbb</span></div>
```

Comment: Шикарно, спасибо

Comment: @Денис Иванов Если вас устраивает ответ **Igor**, отметьте его принятым(ниже кнопок голосования "за" и "против" вопроса).